# How to extend my current elevated deck which is 12'x 12' with a 1-foot lower deck of 12'x12'?

Tags: deck, outdoor

The new deck will be 12'x12' ( less than half will be carved for the pool ).
It will also be about 1 foot lower to fit with the pool.
The existing deck is attached to the house and have 2 commercials screw piles.

I kinda need help and some advice will be really appreciated!

My current plan will be to use joist hangers directly on the support beam which are 3x (2'x8') nailed together. To support the new deck I would use 7 pylex(4x4) screw pile.

1. Is this okay to attach joist hangers on a support beam like this?
2. Are 7 pylex(4x4) sufficient or i should change the technique
   Here are some pictures of the current deck and the support beam

[image: current deck]

[image: current beam that might be used for joist]

Thank you!

Comment: Jurisdiction is relevant as rules can vary, depending on earthquake zone, tornado zone, soil types, etc. It may be worth checking with your local building department. I'd also consider a floating deck around the pool **not attached to the existing deck** - if allowed that will likely be a lot cheaper and easier.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact How do you properly "join" them without attaching them ?

Comment: You don't. The floating deck goes right next to the existing deck, with a very small gap (an inch?) between them. But I don't know if that is allowed (a) in general or (b) wherever you are located.

Comment: I think the OP really wants a "freestanding" deck more than a floating deck.  This seems a bit tall for a floating deck.  Having said that and looking closer at the pics, what is that footing system?  I don't think I've ever seen that before.

Comment: @Huesmann They are commercial adjustable screw piles. Like those -> https://www.goliathtechpiles.com/our-helical-screw-piles

Comment: Huh.  I guess I just thought it odd that so much of the shaft would be exposed.